# Get the last 9 occurances

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL 5.0.12 and I have the following table:

```
| post_id | price | created_at          |
|---------|-------|---------------------|
| 10      | 3.5   | 2018-06-18 07:36:34 |
| 11      | 4.8   | 2018-06-17 07:36:34 |
| 10      | 5     | 2018-06-16 07:36:34 |
| 10      | 5     | 2018-06-15 07:36:34 |
| 6       | 3.6   | 2018-06-12 07:36:34 |
| 10      | 2     | 2018-06-14 07:36:34 |
| 10      | 6     | 2018-06-13 07:36:34 |
| 10      | 9     | 2018-06-12 07:36:34 |
| 10      | 4     | 2018-06-11 07:36:34 |
| 10      | 3.6   | 2018-06-09 07:36:34 |
```

As you can see I have 8 occurrences of the post_id `10`.

As a result I would like to get the last 6 occurrences from today's date.

```
| post_id | price | created_at          |
|---------|-------|---------------------|
| 10      | 3.5   | 2018-06-18 07:36:34 |
| 10      | 5     | 2018-06-16 07:36:34 |
| 10      | 5     | 2018-06-15 07:36:34 |
| 10      | 2     | 2018-06-14 07:36:34 |
| 10      | 6     | 2018-06-13 07:36:34 |
| 10      | 9     | 2018-06-12 07:36:34 |
```

I know how to select the right post_id, but I am struggling with selecting the last 6 occurrences from today's date:

```
SELECT * FROM product where post_id = 10
```

Any suggestions how to get the last 6 occurrences from today's date?

Comment: add to your SELECT query `ORDER by created_at DESC LIMIT 6`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would do it this way :

```
SELECT * FROM product 
WHERE post_id = 10 
ORDER BY created_at DESC 
LIMIT 6
```

You order by the date descending, that way you get at the top the latest ones. And you limit to 6 so you would only get the 6 you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `LIMIT` keyword to get the n first rows of your query. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE post_id = 10 LIMIT 6
```

Keep in mind that this example will return the first 6 rows. You can use the `ORDER BY` keyword to control what the first 6 rows should be.

In your case, you need:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE post_id = 10 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -6 DAY)`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM product 
WHERE post_id = 10 
AND created_at >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -6 DAY)
```

Output:

```
post_id price   created_at
10      3.5     2018-06-18 07:36:34
10      5       2018-06-16 07:36:34
10      5       2018-06-15 07:36:34
10      2       2018-06-14 07:36:34
10      6       2018-06-13 07:36:34
10      9       2018-06-12 07:36:34
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c36fc/1/0